# Matlab best approach to save data in files

Tags: matlab, performance, file

In my program I've added two buttons to save and load default parameters. Right now I'm saving these parameters inside an excel file, which I think that is faster to be read in case one want just to see the default parameters outside Matlab with this approach

```
A = {'Variable 1','Variable 2','Variable 3';
    var1,var2,var3};
filename = fullfile(folder,'name_file.xlsx');
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A1';
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

but I see that the first time that I save, it takes a quite long time (even worst in case the file doesn't exist) and the same when I load the parameters back to my program in the first iteration.
I was thinking: is there any other way to write and read an excel file to save some time? Otherwise I could consider to use a txt file instead of excel

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to save to an excel file as opposed to a ".mat" file? Otherwise there is this [alternate xlswrite](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27236-improved-xlswrite-m)

Comment: No actually, it was just the first thing that I tought in case I want to see the parameters without open matlab. Because in case I use a ".mat" file I should first open matlab or choose to open the file with notepad.

Comment: Is your matrix numerical and you just wish to be able to open it in excel normally?

Comment: Well, only numerical or only characters?

Comment: No I for now I wrote a cell variable where in the first row there is the name of each element (in ascii) and the second row with the variables.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post with an example of this? I was going to suggest [csvwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) which is much faster than xlswrite but I'm not sure that will be possible now. As far as I can tell csvwrite only accepts matrix arguments.

Comment: No problem. I simply define a cell `A` and first I put the names, then the variables

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any good solution for you. If happen to just want to save the numerical values you can use csvwrite which is much faster than xlswrite. Alternatively, you can write to a table and write to csv or xls via [writetable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)

Comment: Writing to disk is always slow, and the more involved the specs of the file format, the worse (thus Excel is way worse than txt, which again is worse than binary). Consider just saving your variables as a .mat file (i.e. MATLAB variable on disk) with `save`, or better still: keeping them around in the workspace, RAM permitting.

Comment: Yes I know this but I want to save in a file because I have different cases and each one has its parameters. I could save as .mat file but in this case I won't have the names if I want to see it outside matab. I will try Durkee's suggestion with the alternate xlswrite and I will look also for a xlsread improved. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

`csvwrite` is much faster that `xlswrite`. You can use `csvwrite` to save it as a comma delimited csv file. which you can also open it with Excel, but `csvwrite` does not accept a `cell` array as input. So you need to save it as matrix:

```
A = [var1,var2,va3];
csvwrite(filename,A);
```

Comment: Not only do you try and steal an answer from me you steal an answer that we already investigated. You put an answer that wasn't a good fit for the problem. Classy

Answer (score 0):

I had a (slightly) similar problem, and knocked up the following approach (in my case it was because I had used `xlswrite` and then moved to a system without it available. `pad_to_string` takes a filename and a cell array with a mix of numeric and string data.

Not sure how easy it is to read back files in this format in Matlab, as I have never tried, but I think `csvread` should handle it.

```
function pad_and_write_to_csv(fname, data)

string_data = cellfun(@data_to_string,data,'UniformOutput',0);
size_data = cellfun(@length,data,'UniformOutput',0);

padded_data = cellfun(@(x) pad_string(x),string_data,'uniformoutput',0);
%From the char matrix, you can use the FPRINTF function to properly output strings to a text file, as shown below:

for i = 1:size(padded_data, 1)
    lines{i} = horzcat(padded_data{i,:});
    lines{i} = lines{i}(1:end-1); % strip trailing comma
end

fid = fopen(fname,'wt');
for i = 1:size(padded_data,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',lines{i});
end
fclose(fid);
```

In file `pad_string.m`

```
function [ out ] = pad_string( in )

% a = length(in);
% out = [char(32*ones(1,str_length-a)), in];

out = [in, ','];
```

In file `data_to_string.m`

```
function [ out ] = data_to_string( in )

in_datatype = class(in);

switch in_datatype
    case 'char'
        out = ['''', in ''''];
    case 'double'
        out = num2str(in);
end
```